# how to set mobile dot steppers in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github, android-gradle-plugin, material-design

I am new to android. I am trying to implement mobile dot steppers with 4 dots.
I downloaded the code from [I added dependency in my android studio 2.3.2](https://github.com/fcannizzaro/material-stepper).
But it shows error while building gradle [image]

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: Without seeing your `build.gradle` I'm assuming you're missing the `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` repository. Otherwise the current version is `1.2.2` so maybe try this one instead.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you this : [steppers](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper)

then make an empty layout like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.stepstone.stepper.StepperLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/stepperLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:ms_stepperType="dots"
    app:ms_stepperFeedbackType="tabs|content|disabled_bottom_navigation" />
```

Finally add in your Activity Layout with include:

```
<include layout="@layout/stepper_layout"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your app module's build.gradle should look like. Like @damian mentioned in the comment, you're probably missing the maven repository block.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


android {
 ...
}

dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'com.github.fcannizzaro:material-stepper:1.0.2'
}
```